# Ubuntu Server Samba Shared Drive Doesn't Appear on Network?

Tags: ubuntu, samba

I'm following this tutorial on an ubuntu server (And trying to access it from my Kubuntu 19.04 laptop connected to the network over ssh):
https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/ins...r-ubuntu-16-04

and cannot seem to get the Samba share to appear in Dolphin.

Neither the server nor my computer had ufw enabled (Confirmed by ufw status). The server's services were restarted using `systemctl restart smbd`

Here are the relevant parts of my smb.conf file (From testparm):

```
root@scilab_comp_0:~# testparm 
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
Processing section "[Anonymous]"
Processing section "[printers]"
Processing section "[print$]"
Loaded services file OK.
Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE

Press enter to see a dump of your service definitions

# Global parameters
[global]
     dns proxy = No
     log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
     map to guest = Bad User
     max log size = 1000
     netbios name = SCILAB_0
     obey pam restrictions = Yes
     pam password change = Yes
     panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
     passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
     passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
     security = USER
     server role = standalone server
     server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
     syslog = 0
     unix password sync = Yes
     usershare allow guests = Yes
     workgroup = SCILAB
     idmap config * : backend = tdb
     guest ok = Yes
     hosts allow = 192.168.1.
     hosts deny = ALL

[Anonymous]
     comment = Scilab File Server
     create mask = 0755
     path = /Data/Shared
     read only = No

root@scilab_comp_0:~# ls -l /Data/Shared/
total 0
drwsrwsr-x+ 1 root sambashare   0 Dec 15 04:46 Alexander
drwsrwsr-x+ 1 root sambashare   0 Dec 15 04:46 Mama
drwsrwsr-x+ 1 root sambashare 140 Dec 14 04:35 MediaServer
```

**Full File:**

```
#
# Sample configuration file for the Samba suite for Debian GNU/Linux.
#
#
# This is the main Samba configuration file. You should read the
# smb.conf(5) manual page in order to understand the options listed
# here. Samba has a huge number of configurable options most of which 
# are not shown in this example
#
# Some options that are often worth tuning have been included as
# commented-out examples in this file.
#  - When such options are commented with ";", the proposed setting
#    differs from the default Samba behaviour
#  - When commented with "#", the proposed setting is the default
#    behaviour of Samba but the option is considered important
#    enough to be mentioned here
#
# NOTE: Whenever you modify this file you should run the command
# "testparm" to check that you have not made any basic syntactic 
# errors. 

#======================= Global Settings =======================

[global]
security=user
hosts allow = 192.168.1.
hosts deny = ALL
netbios name = SCILAB_0
guest ok = yes
## Browsing/Identification ###

# Change this to the workgroup/NT-domain name your Samba server will part of
workgroup = SCILAB

# server string is the equivalent of the NT Description field
 server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)

# Windows Internet Name Serving Support Section:
# WINS Support - Tells the NMBD component of Samba to enable its WINS Server
#   wins support = no

# WINS Server - Tells the NMBD components of Samba to be a WINS Client
# Note: Samba can be either a WINS Server, or a WINS Client, but NOT both
;   wins server = w.x.y.z

# This will prevent nmbd to search for NetBIOS names through DNS.
dns proxy = no

#### Networking ####

# The specific set of interfaces / networks to bind to
# This can be either the interface name or an IP address/netmask;
# interface names are normally preferred
;   interfaces = 127.0.0.0/8 eth0

# Only bind to the named interfaces and/or networks; you must use the
# 'interfaces' option above to use this.
# It is recommended that you enable this feature if your Samba machine is
# not protected by a firewall or is a firewall itself. However, this
# option cannot handle dynamic or non-broadcast interfaces correctly.
;   bind interfaces only = yes

#### Debugging/Accounting ####

# This tells Samba to use a separate log file for each machine
# that connects
log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m

# Cap the size of the individual log files (in KiB).
max log size = 1000

# If you want Samba to only log through syslog then set the following
# parameter to 'yes'.
#   syslog only = no

# We want Samba to log a minimum amount of information to syslog. Everything
# should go to /var/log/samba/log.{smbd,nmbd} instead. If you want to log
# through syslog you should set the following parameter to something higher.
syslog = 0

# Do something sensible when Samba crashes: mail the admin a backtrace
panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d

####### Authentication #######

# Server role. Defines in which mode Samba will operate. Possible
# values are "standalone server", "member server", "classic primary
# domain controller", "classic backup domain controller", "active
# directory domain controller". 
#
# Most people will want "standalone sever" or "member server".
# Running as "active directory domain controller" will require first
# running "samba-tool domain provision" to wipe databases and create a
# new domain.
server role = standalone server

# If you are using encrypted passwords, Samba will need to know what
# password database type you are using.  
passdb backend = tdbsam

obey pam restrictions = yes

# This boolean parameter controls whether Samba attempts to sync the Unix
# password with the SMB password when the encrypted SMB password in the
# passdb is changed.
unix password sync = yes

# For Unix password sync to work on a Debian GNU/Linux system, the following
# parameters must be set (thanks to Ian Kahan <<kahan@informatik.tu-muenchen.de> for
# sending the correct chat script for the passwd program in Debian Sarge).
passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .

# This boolean controls whether PAM will be used for password changes
# when requested by an SMB client instead of the program listed in
# 'passwd program'. The default is 'no'.
pam password change = yes

# This option controls how unsuccessful authentication attempts are mapped
# to anonymous connections
map to guest = bad user

########## Domains ###########

#
# The following settings only takes effect if 'server role = primary
# classic domain controller', 'server role = backup domain controller'
# or 'domain logons' is set 
#

# It specifies the location of the user's
# profile directory from the client point of view) The following
# required a [profiles] share to be setup on the samba server (see
# below)
;   logon path = \\%N\profiles\%U
# Another common choice is storing the profile in the user's home directory
# (this is Samba's default)
#   logon path = \\%N\%U\profile

# The following setting only takes effect if 'domain logons' is set
# It specifies the location of a user's home directory (from the client
# point of view)
;   logon drive = H:
#   logon home = \\%N\%U

# The following setting only takes effect if 'domain logons' is set
# It specifies the script to run during logon. The script must be stored
# in the [netlogon] share
# NOTE: Must be store in 'DOS' file format convention
;   logon script = logon.cmd

# This allows Unix users to be created on the domain controller via the SAMR
# RPC pipe. The example command creates a user account with a disabled Unix
# password; please adapt to your needs
; add user script = /usr/sbin/adduser --quiet --disabled-password --gecos "" %u

# This allows machine accounts to be created on the domain controller via the 
# SAMR RPC pipe.  
# The following assumes a "machines" group exists on the system
; add machine script  = /usr/sbin/useradd -g machines -c "%u machine account" -d /var/lib/samba -s /bin/false %u

# This allows Unix groups to be created on the domain controller via the SAMR
# RPC pipe.  
; add group script = /usr/sbin/addgroup --force-badname %g

############ Misc ############

# Using the following line enables you to customise your configuration
# on a per machine basis. The %m gets replaced with the netbios name
# of the machine that is connecting
;   include = /home/samba/etc/smb.conf.%m

# Some defaults for winbind (make sure you're not using the ranges
# for something else.)
;   idmap uid = 10000-20000
;   idmap gid = 10000-20000
;   template shell = /bin/bash

# Setup usershare options to enable non-root users to share folders
# with the net usershare command.

# Maximum number of usershare. 0 (default) means that usershare is disabled.
;   usershare max shares = 100

# Allow users who've been granted usershare privileges to create
# public shares, not just authenticated ones
usershare allow guests = yes

#======================= Share Definitions =======================

# Un-comment the following (and tweak the other settings below to suit)
# to enable the default home directory shares. This will share each
# user's home directory as \\server\username
;[homes]
;   comment = Home Directories
;   browseable = no

# By default, the home directories are exported read-only. Change the
# next parameter to 'no' if you want to be able to write to them.
;   read only = yes

# File creation mask is set to 0700 for security reasons. If you want to
# create files with group=rw permissions, set next parameter to 0775.
;   create mask = 0700

# Directory creation mask is set to 0700 for security reasons. If you want to
# create dirs. with group=rw permissions, set next parameter to 0775.
;   directory mask = 0700

# By default, \\server\username shares can be connected to by anyone
# with access to the samba server.
# Un-comment the following parameter to make sure that only "username"
# can connect to \\server\username
# This might need tweaking when using external authentication schemes
;   valid users = %S

# Un-comment the following and create the netlogon directory for Domain Logons
# (you need to configure Samba to act as a domain controller too.)
;[netlogon]
;   comment = Network Logon Service
;   path = /home/samba/netlogon
;   guest ok = yes
;   read only = yes

# Un-comment the following and create the profiles directory to store
# users profiles (see the "logon path" option above)
# (you need to configure Samba to act as a domain controller too.)
# The path below should be writable by all users so that their
# profile directory may be created the first time they log on
;[profiles]
;   comment = Users profiles
;   path = /home/samba/profiles
;   guest ok = no
;   browseable = no
;   create mask = 0600
;   directory mask = 0700
[Anonymous]
 comment = Scilab File Server
 path = /Data/Shared
 browsable = yes
 writable = yes
 guest ok = yes
 read only = no
 #force user = nobody
 create mask = 0755
[printers]
comment = All Printers
browseable = no
path = /var/spool/samba
printable = yes
guest ok = no
read only = yes
create mask = 0700

# Windows clients look for this share name as a source of downloadable
# printer drivers
[print$]
comment = Printer Drivers
path = /var/lib/samba/printers
browseable = yes
read only = yes
guest ok = no
# Uncomment to allow remote administration of Windows print drivers.
# You may need to replace 'lpadmin' with the name of the group your
# admin users are members of.
# Please note that you also need to set appropriate Unix permissions
# to the drivers directory for these users to have write rights in it
;   write list = root, @lpadmin
```

**EDIT 0:**
I installed avahi-daemon and checked its status:

```
Dec 17 17:41:32 scilab_comp_0 avahi-daemon[7358]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface lo.IPv6 with address ::1.
Dec 17 17:41:32 scilab_comp_0 avahi-daemon[7358]: New relevant interface lo.IPv6 for mDNS.
Dec 17 17:41:32 scilab_comp_0 avahi-daemon[7358]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface lo.IPv4 with address 127.0.0.1.
Dec 17 17:41:32 scilab_comp_0 avahi-daemon[7358]: New relevant interface lo.IPv4 for mDNS.
Dec 17 17:41:32 scilab_comp_0 avahi-daemon[7358]: Network interface enumeration completed.
Dec 17 17:41:32 scilab_comp_0 avahi-daemon[7358]: Registering new address record for fe80::225:64ff:feaf:9fc8 on enp0s25.*.
Dec 17 17:41:32 scilab_comp_0 avahi-daemon[7358]: Registering new address record for 192.168.1.222 on enp0s25.IPv4.
Dec 17 17:41:32 scilab_comp_0 avahi-daemon[7358]: Registering new address record for ::1 on lo.*.
Dec 17 17:41:32 scilab_comp_0 avahi-daemon[7358]: Registering new address record for 127.0.0.1 on lo.IPv4.
Dec 17 17:41:33 scilab_comp_0 avahi-daemon[7358]: Server startup complete. Host name is scilabcomp0.local. Local service cookie is
```

However, running a test on localhost fails:

```
root@scilab_comp_0:~# smbclient -L localhost
WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
protocol negotiation failed: NT_STATUS_INVALID_NETWORK_RESPONSE
```

Comment: More importantly, are you able to _connect_ to the Samba share via `smb://192.168.1.x`?

Comment: I tried a few entries and the only one that worked was `192.168.1.222` which is the server's static ip address. That's a bit strange. I would have though that Dolphin would have discovered it on the network. Also, why does it work only with the server's (static) ip address? Also, given that I'm going to be using this with people unfamiliar with Samba, I kind of need it to have low configuration. Can I make it discoverable on the net or do I need to manually point it via shortcut?

Comment: I'm not sure what other addresses you have tried? When connecting to the server, the server's own IP address is the only address that makes sense...

Comment: I suppose it's my newness to Samba then. I should have tried that first. But I don't understand why Dolphin doesn't find it. Ditto for the windows computers on the network.

Answer (score 0):

Network computer discovery is a bit separate from the actual file-sharing connection and uses different protocols. (And accessing the server by its hostname is mostly separate from both as well.)

There are actually three different protocols which can be used for discovery, and none of them have 100% support (though NetBIOS comes very close):

- NetBIOS: The traditional mechanism that was used on all Windows and even MS-DOS versions. Supported on Linux by the **`nmbd`** daemon which is part of Samba. However, on Windows 10 systems it is now disabled by default and requires SMBv1 support to be re-enabled against Microsoft's recommendations.
- WS-Discovery: The new mechanism for Windows 7–10, but not supported by Linux at all.
- mDNS: Supported on Linux by the Avahi daemon and recognized by macOS, but not yet by Windows. (That is, Windows can use it only to look up hostnames, but *not* to discover shared folders.)

So first make sure that the server has both **`nmbd`** and `avahi-daemon` services enabled – this should cover most systems (including most Windows installations, although not necessarily all of them due to NetBIOS being tied to SMBv1).

If the server has a firewall, don't forget to open the new ports – mDNS (Avahi) needs to be able to receive packets on `5353/udp`, while NetBIOS uses `137-138/udp` and `139/tcp`.

Finally, if you use NetBIOS (nmbd), make sure the server and all clients have identical **`workgroup`** settings in smb.conf.

Comment: (Launched on the server): `smbclient -L localhost` led to an error: protocol negotiation failed: NT_STATUS_INVALID_NETWORK_RESPONSE. The smbd service was running at the time.